# Connect GCP Redis INSTANCE in my AWS EKS cluster

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, redis

I have created a VPN tunnel for my GCP and AWS with this documentation [Create HA VPN connections between Google Cloud and AWS](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/tutorials/create-ha-vpn-connections-google-cloud-aws)

Also I refer this video [GCP - How to build HA VPN connections between Google Cloud and AWS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y58hhDiLbNI) and follow all the steps, as checked my tunnel is working fine.

Then I have created my cluster in AWS EKS in a VPC and my redis instance in a VPC.Both vpc are connected trough tunnel. In my AWS I have stored my GCP service account key in AWS secrets manager and attached it with the help of csi drive. All other GCP services are running fine like firebase, spanner, etc also I have given admin access so there shouldn't  be any access issue. This is my deployment yaml looks like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-deployment-sa
      volumes:
      - name: secrets-store-inline
        csi:
          driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
          readOnly: true
          volumeAttributes:
            secretProviderClass: "aws-secrets"
      containers:
      - name: my-app-container
        image: **************.amazonaws.com/my-app:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
          readOnly: true
```

This is my secret provider class:

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: aws-secrets
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:
    objects: |
        - objectName: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:******************"
        - objectName: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:******************"
```

I am getting this error:

```
$kubectl logs po/my-app-1j3kd34dk-kv4j34   
helloworld: listening on port 8080
ERR:REDIS: ConnectionTimeoutError: Connection timeout
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:178:124)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:550:8)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

This is my redis connection code in node:

```
    const redis = require('redis');
    const { REDIS_PORT, REDIS_IP_ADDRESS } = require('./const.js');
    
    class RedisSingleton {
      constructor() {
        if (!RedisSingleton.instance) {
          const client = redis.createClient({
            socket: {
              port: REDIS_PORT,
              host: REDIS_IP_ADDRESS,
            },
          });
    
          this.subClient = client;
          this.subClient.on("error", (err) => console.error("ERR:REDIS:", err));
          this.subClient.connect();
          
          RedisSingleton.instance = this;
        }
    
        return RedisSingleton.instance;
      }
    }
    
    const instance = new RedisSingleton();
    Object.freeze(instance);

module.exports = instance;
```